# LibGit2Sharp - invalid pack file - delta offset is zero

Tags: git, libgit2sharp

I have a window service that pulls from my repository. Whenever I tried to pull from the repository using LibGit2Sharp I end up with this error `invalid pack file - delta offset is zero`. Upon surfing the internet, the only close resource I got is [this](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/issues/1835) and it was not even answered. The pack file from my local repository is around 5GB. The repository has around 20-40 branches with lots of commits and the actual size of the files on each branch size is around 1GB-2GB.

From what I have read, there is a possibility that the repository is big.

I need to provide a permanent fix. Does anybody know what causes this and how to fix this?